# How can I send a method with it's generic type to RXJS bindCallback?

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, rxjs

I need to pass a function with callback to `bindCallback` rxjs function. But my function has generic type.

This is the code:

```js
const obCreator = bindCallback<T>(FakeServer.instance.on<T>);
return obCreator(module, method);
```

This is the error in the first line:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 34, '(callbackFunc:
> (callback: (res1: T) => any) => any, scheduler?: SchedulerLike |
> undefined): () => Observable', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(callback: (res1: T) => any) => any'.

This has no error but no generics:

```js
const obCreator = bindCallback(FakeServer.instance.on);
return obCreator(module, method);
```

Comment: Looking at the error, looks like your call back is not returning anything, means return void try changing some value like giving back a boolean or a string or array whatever... But not void...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/bindCallback) the first signature of `bindCallback` is

```
bindCallback<T>(callbackFunc: Function, resultSelector?: Function | SchedulerLike, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): (...args: any[]) => Observable<T>
```

which means that you can pass a generic type to `bindCallback` but the function passed as input does not have any generic. Therefore you should be able to use the following form

```
const obCreator = bindCallback<T>(FakeServer.instance.on);
return obCreator(module, method);  // returns an Observable<T>
```

There are no other overloads which accept generics, so this seems to be the only option, and probably there is no
According this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-sajem1) this should work.